# visual basic calculator without using decision structures or loops

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, sequential

1st year coding student and have a project in my visual basics class.

Create a simple calculator that will multiply, divide, subtract and add. Thing is we are not allowed to use any decision structures or loops, only sequential style coding structure.

I am struggling with storing, passing, and utilizing the selected mathematical operator later in the program.

When coding equations, what data type are operators considered?

For example in 4-1=3 is - considered a string?

How would one go about storing this value and passing it to another section of the program then converting that to a form you could plug into a formula, all without using a decision structure or loop?

for example:

1) User clicks on "1" button a string value of 1 is stored in a label as a string.

2) The user clicks the the "+" button and a + is stored (not sure what data type to use here for later needs) in a label.

3) Then user clicks "1" button a 1 is stored in a label as a string.

4) User clicks the "=" button.

5) The = button event handler executes code converting both the "1" strings to integer variables and the formula should represent IntResult= IntvariableOne + intVariableTwo. but since the operator may not always be + and no decision structure can be used. how can this be coded in a way that uses a variable to store the operator and complete the processing correctly in a formula?

In the most simple terms it would be equivalent to something like:
intResult= intvariableOne, Operatorvarible, intVariableTwo 
Like I said I am new to coding so I apologize if this is a dumb question or completely wrong approach.

any info is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a cheat, but try using `Eval`:

```
Eval("4-1")  ' returns 3
```

Comment: Because this is an assignment, I will not tell you how I would do it. But I will give you a hint: imagine a list of objects that you could execute sequentially to calculate the result. The calculator keys create this list, and the = key executes the sequential calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post I was thinking about using the "[CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function)" function.

---

**But** you can also try something more elegant with some kind of "oop" (reaching some of the limits offered by the old VB6) :

Create a file "ICalculator.cls" :

```
'
' Defines the "ICalculator" interface.
'
Option Explicit

Public Function CalcProcess(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer)

End Function
```

Create a file named "CalculatorAdd.cls" that will take "additions" in charge:

```
'
' This "class" will implement "ICalculator" inteface to manage additions.
'
Option Explicit
Implements ICalculator

Private Function ICalculator_CalcProcess(value1 As Integer, value2 As Integer)
    ICalculator_CalcProcess = value1 + value2
End Function
```

An then, an example of how it works :

```
Sub Test()

Dim value1 As Integer
Dim value2 As Integer

value1 = 1
value2 = 2

' Global object :
Dim objCalculator As ICalculator
...

' The object is set to "Addition" in the onclick event of the "add" button :
Set objCalculator = New CalculatorAdd
...

' The process is done in the onclick event of the "equal" button
value1 = objCalculator.CalcProcess(value1, value2)
...

' You can also have :
'Set objCalculator = New CalculatorSub
'value1 = objCalculator.CalcProcess(value1, value2)
'etc...

End Sub
```

You can create classes for each operation "add, sub, divide, multiply" and set your global variable **objCalculator** according to the button pressed by the user.

That's just a beginning, you'll have to  put the whole logic of a calculator in place...